# Slowly printing characters like in old school games in Python

Tags: python, character, launcher

my problem is as follows:

I want my program to print out characters slowly one after another.
With the Code provided further down it works just as intended if I run the module via PythonShell.
If I run it with the PythonLauncher it shows me the text one **line** after another everytime a new line begins after the time passed that it takes to write out a line.

```
import time
def slowCharacters(x,y):
    sC = str(x)
    speed = int(y)/100
    for i in range(0,len(sC),1):
        print(sC[i], end = "")
        time.sleep(speed)

slowCharacters("""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l""",10)
```

Comment: Using `print(sC[i], end = "", flush=True)` might help.

Comment: Yes! That was it, thank you very much!